# how do I change lookdevreflections

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: how do I change lookdev reflections]

hi guys, is there any possibilities to change these mirror ball reflections to my interior scene reflections. as you can see this doesn't looks very good... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to check these squares in to allow screen space reflections:[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answers FFeller, but it doesn't seems working... I've checked all those boxes and it only does makes my floor refraction disappeared

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't noticed the Lookdev word. Click on Shading (upper right corner of 3d view) than check in Scene Lights and Scene World. Then the objects will reflect on your spheres.

Comment: yes, I tried to so. but it seems still doesn't reflect any objects in the scene except floor object or any object that really close to this mirror ball (wall, desk, armchair still doesn't included).